# AngularJS + Android 4.2: very slow to react

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Our web app is built with AngularJS v1.2.26 We're troubleshooting an issue that only seems to happen on older Android browsers, specifically 4.2...

In short, asynchronous things are happening ~600% slower than they should. For example, we show an error message in response to a failed HTTP request. The service in charge of making the request has a variable which holds status messages. Then a controller watches it like this:

```
// Status msg ctrl
var statusCtrl = app.controller('statusCtrl', function($scope, updateService, $timeout) {

  $scope.message = false;
  //watch for status messages
  $scope.$watch(function () { return updateService.loadingTroubleMsg; },
    function (value) {
        $scope.message = value;
    }
  );

});
```

In other browsers this works perfectly. The http request fails and then the message appears right away. On the Android browser (which the client is running from a USB) the message shows up ~20 minutes later.

I have a couple theories:

1. The promise is taking a very long time to be resolved,
2. The `$watch` is happing in slow motion.
3. The http request is taking a reallllly long time to timeout.

There are no visible errors, and everything else seems to work. Unfortunately, I do not have the exact USB Android device in my position, which makes troubleshooting more difficult.

Why would this happen? Are any of my theories more plausible then the others? Any advice on how to get to the bottom of this is welcome.

Comment: `promises` are a very expensive "sintaxic sugar" for JS applications. Why not to make it more natural way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be #3. I added a "timeout" limit to the $http config settings and it started responding normally. I don't know why this only mattered on Android 4.2. I'm guessing it's related to its lack of (native) support for promises.